# Convert a Named tuple into a dictionary in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm using a package that downloads favicons from websites.

It has 4 components (Not key-value pairs) and its corresponding values for each element in the list.

```
url='https://www.python.org/',
width=200,
height=200,
format='png'
```

My purpose is to convert each element in the list(containing the 4 components) same into a key:value pair as in a dictionary in this way:

```
'url':'https://www.python.org/',
'width':200,
'height':200,
'format':'png',
```

My following attempt didnt yield the correct result.

Here is my attempt :

```html
import favicon

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
url = 'https://www.python.org/'
icons = favicon.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=2)
print(f"Before:{icons}")

my_dict = {}

for index,element in enumerate(icons):
    my_dict[index] = element

print(f"After:{my_dict}")
```

The result of

> print(f"Before:{icons}) is

```html
    [Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png', width=200, height=200, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/metro-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', width=114, height=114, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', width=72, height=72, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', width=0, height=0, format='png'), Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico')]
```

And the result after enumerating through it and building a dictionary:

> print(f"After:{my_dict}") is

```html
After:{0: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png', width=200, height=200, format='png'), 1: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/metro-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'), 2: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'), 3: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', width=114, height=114, format='png'), 4: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', width=72, height=72, format='png'), 5: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico'), 6: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', width=0, height=0, format='png'), 7: Icon(url='https://www.python.org/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico')}
```

How I Want it to look as for only the 1st object :

```
icon :{ "url": "python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png", 
        "width": 200, 
        "height": 200, 
        "format": "png", }
```

If possible, I would be happy to see it for all the objects too in the format listed above.

Kindly assist !

Comment: *convert each element in the list(containing the 4 components)* - how should it look?

Comment: Hi. Just updated the question for how it should look.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dangee. Its there in the question.Pls read.

Comment: Do you know that a dictionary with monotonically increasing integer keys is the same as a list?

Comment: @Earthling, `{Icon ...` - you don't need an external class instance as a dict key

Comment: Maybe take a look at what the enumerate function is actually doing and read the documentation for the favicon library on how to access the values you are looking for

Comment: You don't need a dictionary. What you posted is an HTTP call using a custom module, `favicon`. Not a list. `print` shows that `icons` is a list of `Icon` objects, not a list of strings. You can already access each `Icon` object by index and retrieve the properties by name. You can't do that with a dictionary

Comment: eg `for icon in icons: print(icon.url)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Forgive me for my limited understating since I'm a newbie. Since I just need to iterate through the object , Could you be willing to show me in a dictionary format since I need to attach it to an existing dictionary using update ()

Comment: What does your data actually look like? What is `Icon()`?

Comment: @JonSG It's a [namedtuple](https://github.com/scottwernervt/favicon/blob/123e431f53b2c4903b540246a85db0b1633d4786/src/favicon/favicon.py#L40)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://github.com/scottwernervt/favicon

Comment: @JonSG https://github.com/scottwernervt/favicon

Comment: Are you looking to do `{i:v._asdict() for i,v in enumerate(icons)}`?

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```py
import collections

Icon = collections.namedtuple('Icon', ['url', 'width', 'height', 'format'])

icons = [
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png', width=200, height=200, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/metro-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', width=144, height=144, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', width=114, height=114, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', width=72, height=72, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', width=0, height=0, format='png'),
    Icon(url='https://www.python.org/static/favicon.ico', width=0, height=0, format='ico')
]
```

If you want to turn the list of `collections.namedtuple()` above into a dictionary with keys of indexes then you can do this:

```py
icons_dicts = {i:v._asdict() for i,v in enumerate(icons)}
print(icons_dicts)
```

If you want to turn that list of `collections.namedtuple()` into a list of dictionaries you can do this.

```py
icons_list = [v._asdict() for v in icons]
print(icons_list)
```

If you want to see the results formatted in a nice way you might add in a call to `json.dumps()`.

```py
import json
icons_list = [v._asdict() for v in icons]
print(json.dumps(icons_list, indent=4))
```

That will give you:

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/metro-icon-144x144-precomposed.png",
        "width": 144,
        "height": 144,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png",
        "width": 144,
        "height": 144,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png",
        "width": 114,
        "height": 114,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png",
        "width": 72,
        "height": 72,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/favicon.ico",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "format": "ico"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "format": "png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.python.org/static/favicon.ico",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "format": "ico"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Jon.  It is the 2nd one --> print(icons_list) that is what I wanted. It is a list of dictionary--> key value pairs.

Comment: However, If you could please check the question again : Your answer is close to what I wanted but may require minor modifications. While the key:value pairs is what I wanted , I actually need it in the format I specified in the updated question

Comment: Is the issue just a display issue?  You want to see it nicely formatted?  If so `json.dumps()` is what you want. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Hi.Sorry to bother you again Jon. Just need it in a nested format. Like --->   icon :{ "url": "https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200,
        "format": "png"
    }

Comment: Hi, it is hard to see from the comment, how you want this formatted. Are you looking to have the key/value pairs line up with the braces?

Comment: Hi. Just updated the question for the format desired since the comment above by me is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add some elements add them in the items list and that should be it

this code goes through the icons extracted from the website and puts them in a dictionary with the items in the `list(items)`

hope this helps :D

```
items=['url',"width","height","format"]
final_dict={}
for icon in range(len(icons[0])):
    final_dict[items[icon]]=icons[0][icon]
print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Hi @RedPotato. This is for only the 1st element in the list of objects. Could you show me (just for learning) how do we do it for all the objects?

Comment: Hello, sorry what do you mean by for all the objects

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being clear enough. What I meant was you did it for the the 1st object i.e object at index 0. I was thinking of the all the other objects too in the list. Also one more thing : I need to update my existing dictionary with the above solution of yours. The final dictionary that I'm trying is for eg : {'title':'sometitle', image : 'someimageurl', icon : {url: 'someurl', 'height':height, 'width':somewidth, format:'someformat'}}

Comment: so you mean in the case of having multiple icons? edit :i looked back at the example given and i want to thank you for pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: Yup. Bu your solution works too since I need the largest icon in the response that I receive made it easier for me : P .

Comment: have updated the question. Could you please check the where I have written "How I Want it to look as for only the 1st object : "